# The trace of a matrix in characteristic p

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm wondering why, in characteristic $p$ ($p$ prime) is $\text{tr} A^p = (\text{tr}A)^p$. I know it has something to do with the fact that $(a+b)^p = a^p + b^p$ in char $p$. But I'm missing that silly crucial step to connect the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A$ have Jordan form $A = VJV^{-1}$. Then, $A^p = VJ^pV^{-1}$.

If the diagonal entries of $J$ are $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$, then the diagonal entries of $J^p$ are $\lambda_1^p, \cdots, \lambda_n^p$.

Hence, $\text{tr}(J^p) = \lambda_1^p + \cdots + \lambda_n^p = (\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n)^p = (\text{tr}(J))^p$.

Finally, since the trace of a matrix is invariant under similarity transforms, $\text{tr}(J^p) = (\text{tr}(J))^p$ becomes $\text{tr}(VJ^pV^{-1}) = (\text{tr}(VJV^{-1}))^p$, i.e. $\text{tr}(A^p) = (\text{tr}(A))^p$, as desired.